# How to use writeUTF() in python? (socket connecting with android studio)

Tags: python, android, sockets

```
# server.py 
import socket
import logging
message = u"GET~CARD\n"
size = len(message)
host = '----' #  ip
port = 9999            #  port


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
server_sock.bind((host, port))
server_sock.listen(1)


print("waiting")
client_sock, addr = server_sock.accept()

print('Connected by', addr)
data = client_sock.recv(1024)
print(data.decode("utf-8"), len(data))


while True:
    sendData = input('>>>')
    client_sock.send(sendData.encode('utf-8'))
    logger.info("sendlog")


    recvData = client_sock.recv(1024)
    print('client :', recvData.decode('utf-8'))
    logger.info("recievelog")
```

First I want to say sorry for not good at using English. I usually use google translator.

The upper code is my server.py code.

And I used

```
  is = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
  os = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
```

and readUTF();, writeUTF(); on Android Studio.

problem is that I can recieve messages on python server, but cant' in android client. I searched for it and I knew that readUTF() can only read one taht wrote in writeUTF().
So I want to get some help for connecting python and android, sending string message each other. is there any good way for it?

Comment: If you know the difference between writeUTF() and write then adapting your python code is done quick.

Comment: Im sorry but I didnt understand it, I only know about they are handling string, int on each.

Comment: writeUTF is the same as write except that it sends two leading bytes indicating the length of the following string.